# How to take value from DataValueField() of a Kendo().DropDownList() on change event

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui-mvc

I'm using kendo grid and editor template for showing my data. in editor I've given id to DataValueField() and name to DataTextField() of kendo dropdown list. In change event, I'm not able to get the DataValueField(). see the following code

This is my editor template MemoCarrier.chtml

```
@using System.Collections
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
  .DataValueField("PARTNERID")
  .DataTextField("PARTNERNAME")

  .Name("AIRLINENAME")
  .BindTo((IEnumerable)ViewBag.lstAirline)
  .HtmlAttributes(new { maxlength = "", @class = "MNum" })
 .OptionLabel("-Select-Flight ")
 .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
 .Events(e =>
 {
   e.Change("MemoCarrier");
 })
)
```

Here is my on change function

```
function MemoCarrier(e) {
    var AirlineName = this.value();
    alert(AirlineName) //it displays PARTNERNAME instead of PARTNERID
}
```

Currently I'm getting name ie;DataTextField() value. instead of that, I need DataValueField(). 
Thanks for suggestions in advance!

Comment: how are you accessing the drop down editor from the grid? Is it via a UIHint or a custom template? You should be able to avoid using a change function and just bind the dropdown to the value provided in the grid by using the data-bind attribute.

Comment: @DavidShorthosehi,im using custom template. how to use data-bind attribute? can you provide me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so based on your comment the easiest way to do this would probably use the `data-bind` attribute to simplify the process of binding the model. Assuming you are using the MVC helper for the grid as well.

so taking your code and adding this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
  .DataValueField("PARTNERID")
  .DataTextField("PARTNERNAME")

  .Name("AIRLINENAME")
  .BindTo((IEnumerable)ViewBag.lstAirline)
  .HtmlAttributes(new { maxlength = "", @class = "MNum", data_bind="value:{yourProperyNameHere}" })
 .OptionLabel("-Select-Flight ")
 .Filter(FilterType.Contains)

)
```

So hopefully you can see all I am doing is adding a new `HtmlAttribute` property to the control for you. All you need to do is put whatever property is meant to be the value for this.

Depending on if this value is a complex (`object`) or simple (`string, int etc`) primitive type you may need to set the `Primitive` property to `true` so that only the valuefield e.g the id you are assigning is bound back to the grid's row model.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Half Done. can i add multiple items in data_bind ? like data_bind = "value:{PARTNER_ID},data-code:{PARTNERCODE1}"

Comment: data_bind is intended to bind to values, events, attributes and any custom binders you may have defined. If you want to add another `data` property to the control then you would add it like `data_code={YourValue}`

Comment: How can i access the 'data_code' attribute value using jquery? like var code = $('#id').attr('data_code') .this is where i stucked ! Thank you so much for help

Comment: you should be able to access it like this `$('#id').data('code')` as it will be part of the data collection

Comment: HtmlAttributes(new { maxlength = "", @class = "" , data_bind = "{PARTNER_ID}", data_code = "{PARTNERCODE1}" })   i gave like this and in javascript i tried $('#id').data('code'). im getting output as string "{PARTNERCODE1}". something small mistake happend.. correct me please

Comment: where is partnercode1 coming from? is it in the row model? If it is then you may need to add this attribute to the control when you launch the onEdit command of the grid.

Comment: im binding a list to the drop-down list using ViewBag.lstAirline.list have PARTNER_ID,PARTNERNAME,PARTNERCODE,etc so my question is like,can we have anything like we are doing for normal<select> <option value="" data-id="" data-code=""> </option></select> .how can i give attributes like this in kendo?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198195/discussion-between-david-shorthose-and-nijin-koderi).